# How to find which user did bill after PayPal billing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I use in my Ruby on Rails app PayPal `Buy now`button with the next code:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SOME_VALUE_HERE">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/IL/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
```

In my page where I put PayPal button I have an user email(inside of variable). In the button setting I show that if success billing - redirect to "my-website.com/success" else "/cancel" page.

So, how can I know that THIS user did bill and write to db about it? How can I pass or save a user email for selecting in table? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use session in this case. Before calling paypal action you can add `session['current_user_id'] = current_user.id` which will be accessible when you get success from paypal